# write EPROTO B8150000:error:0A000152:SSL routines:final_renegotiate:unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

When I try to install any package on NPM, I'm getting the error below;

```
47 verbose stack FetchError: request to https://artifactory.thy.com/artifactory/api/npm/kac-npm/@angular%2fcli failed, reason: write EPROTO B8150000:error:0A000152:SSL routines:final_renegotiate: unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled: c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\statem\extensions.c:908:
```

NodeJS Version: 18
NPM Version: 8

Comment: Just happened to me on 18.12.1 installed yesterday on production server.  Is this reported to nodejs?

Answer (score 4):

I fixed the problem by reverting back to NodeJS LTS Version(NodeJS V16.17)

Comment: same here. Tried and failed with 18.11 and 18.12, fall back to 16.18

Comment: please try with 16.17 ?

Comment: why 16.17? I am working fine on 16.18, only that it fails on 18.11 and 18.12

Answer (score 3):

I know this post is a few months old, but instead of falling back to an older version, this solution from this MadDocNC worked for me and allowed me to use the latest version of Node 18. https://stackoverflow.com/a/74600467/2950027