# AxiosError: write EPROTO C0D7BC0EAE7F0000

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I'm getting this error while trying send a post request to an endpoint. I don't know what to do and actually couldn't find anything about it. Could you please help me? Thanks a lot!

Here is how my axios request looks like:

```
const config = {
    headers: {
      accept: "*/*",
      "accept-language": "tr,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8",
      "cache-control": "no-cache",
      "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
      pragma: "no-cache",
      "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
      "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin",
    },
  };

  const url =
    process.env.MODE === "TEST"
      ? "https://earsivportaltest.efatura.gov.tr/earsiv-services/assos-login"
      : "https://earsivportal.efatura.gov.tr/earsiv-services/assos-login";

  const assoscmd = process.env.MODE === "TEST" ? "login" : "anologin";

  const response = await axios.post(
    `${url}`,
    {
      assoscmd: assoscmd,
      userid: userId,
      sifre: password,
      sifre2: password,
      parola: 1,
    },
    config
  );
  return response.data;
```

Here is my error:

```
AxiosError: write EPROTO C0D7BC0EAE7F0000:error:0A000152:SSL routines:final_renegotiate:unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/statem/extensions.c:922:

    at AxiosError.from (/mnt/D/Yedekler/30 Aralık/Belgeler/fatura/node_modules/axios/dist/node/axios.cjs:789:14)
    at RedirectableRequest.handleRequestError (/mnt/D/Yedekler/30 Aralık/Belgeler/fatura/node_modules/axios/dist/node/axios.cjs:2744:25)
    at RedirectableRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at eventHandlers.<computed> (/mnt/D/Yedekler/30 Aralık/Belgeler/fatura/node_modules/follow-redirects/index.js:14:24)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:494:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  syscall: 'write',
  code: 'EPROTO',
  errno: -71,
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replying to an old question, but if anyone has a similar problem it can be solved modifying [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74600467/6807599) slightly.

require the following :

```js
const https = require('https');
const crypto = require('node:crypto');
```

then add

```
httpsAgent: new https.Agent({secureOptions: crypto.constants.SSL_OP_LEGACY_SERVER_CONNECT})
```

or

```js
httpsAgent: new https.Agent({secureOptions: crypto.constants.SSL_OP_ALLOW_UNSAFE_LEGACY_RENEGOTIATION}),
```

to your config like this :

```js
const config = {
    headers: {
      ...
    },
    httpsAgent: new https.Agent({secureOptions: crypto.constants.SSL_OP_LEGACY_SERVER_CONNECT}),    
  };
```

This will solve the `final_renegotiate:unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled:.` issue. Read more about [OpenSSL options](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#openssl-options) of the **node:crypto** module, or [SSL_OP_FLags](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/List_of_SSL_OP_Flags#Table_of_Options) for other options.