# Error with axios post SSL routines:final_renegotiate:unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled

Tags: node.js, axios

I am receiving the following error: `EPROTO B8150000:error:0A000152:SSL routines:final_renegotiate:unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled` when performing an axios post request.

```
function makeRequest(url: string, data: object) {
  return axios({
    url,
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    method: 'POST',
    data: { some: 'data' },
  });
}
```

What I want to know is why the API request works successfully against the endpoint I am calling when using Postman. But not when I use a node/axios and whether there is another approach? (such as reaching out to the API endpoint owner to update their SSL/TLS settings)

I am using `node version 18.17.1`

I have found a solution, but it is not recommended:

```
/**
 * Handle this problem with Node 18
 * write EPROTO B8150000:error:0A000152:SSL routines:final_renegotiate:unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled
 * see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74324019/allow-legacy-renegotiation-for-nodejs/74600467#74600467
 **/
const allowLegacyRenegotiationforNodeJsOptions = {
  httpsAgent: new https.Agent({
    // for self signed you could also add
    // rejectUnauthorized: false,
    // allow legacy server
    secureOptions: crypto.constants.SSL_OP_LEGACY_SERVER_CONNECT,
  }),
};

function makeRequest(url: string, data: object) {
  return axios({
    ...allowLegacyRenegotiationforNodeJsOptions,
    url,
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    method: 'POST',
    data: { some: 'data' },
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Postman is probably being used in dev mode. So it might ignore errors.

You can wrap your api inside cloudflare (serch for it on the great internet) so that the SSL of cloudflare will be the one facing the web.

The problem is surely on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

I see Node version 18 has disabled unsafe legacy TLS renegotiation by default, refer this [link](https://dev.to/johnnyreilly/nodejs-18-axios-and-unsafe-legacy-renegotiation-disabled-18ki)

So you can try to set the secureOptions option of the httpsAgent object to crypto.constants.SSL_OP_LEGACY_SERVER_CONNECT. It will allow Node to connect to the API endpoint while its using legacy TLS renegotiation.

Here you go:

```js
function makeRequest(url: string, data: object) {
  return axios({
    url,
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    method: 'POST',
    data: { some: 'data' },
    httpsAgent: new https.Agent({
      secureOptions: crypto.constants.SSL_OP_LEGACY_SERVER_CONNECT,
    }),
  });
}
```